# Let $X = A\cup B$. Show that $V$ is an open subset of $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = A\cup B$, $V \subset A \cap B$ and $V \cap A$ be an open subset of $A$. Also let $V \cap B$ be an open subset of $B$. Show that $V$ is an open subset of $X$.

This seems very confusing. I'm not sure why they have all these conditions. I'm not sure what definitions I could use here to show this... How can I start approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions first: $V \cap A$ is an open subset of $A$ means that there is an open set $O_1$ of $X$ such that $O_1 \cap A = V \cap A$. Similarly, $V \cap B$ is an open subset of $B$ means that there is an open set $O_2$ of $X$ such that $O_2 \cap B = V \cap B$.

Now, if $x \in V$, we know that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ as $V \subseteq A \cap B$. So $x \in A \cap V = O_1 \cap V$, and so $x \in O_1$, *and* $x \in B \cap V = O_2 \cap V$ so $x \in O_2$.

So $V \subseteq O_1 \cap O_2$. We would be done if the reverse inclusion also held, as a finite intersection of open sets is open.
So let $x \in O_1 \cap O_2$. Then we have $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ as $X=A \cup B$.
In the first case $x \in O_1 \cap A= A \cap V \subseteq V$ and in the second $x \in O_2 \cap B = V \cap B \subseteq V$, so we're done showing the other inclusion.

So $$V = O_1 \cap O_2$$ is open in $X$. Check: we exactly used all the given assumptions.